# How not to redirect HTML file to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am very new to php just today itself I have started learning it, I am doing a simple program from of selecting a row from mysql's database based on user input on html through php file . and my concern is when I submit the form , it redirects to to the php and the output is displayed on the php, how can I display the result on the HTML page itself I mean the user shouldn't feel there is any transition from html to php any we get the output on the html page

HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="get">
    Enter Name : <input type="text" id="txt1" name="user">
    <input type="submit" name="enter">
    </form>
</body>
```

php page :

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";

 mysql_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
 @mysql_select_db("trynew") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET["user"])) {
$user = $_GET['user'];

}
$query = "SELECT * FROM trynewtable where name = '$user' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result==FALSE)
{
die(mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Put your html into the php file.

Comment: If i understood correctly, you should use jquery and send data to php file with it. ( if you dont want to reload page).

Comment: Read the introduction to php on php.net

Comment: what need for this behaviour is called 'ajax'. You will find plenty of examples online.

Comment: @Jeff : a beginner with php shouldnt start with advanced js at the same time

Comment: **Do not use `mysql_` functions but use `mysqli_`.** A single Google query will tell you why.

Comment: i think try @Jonasw idea of putting the HTML code in the php file

Comment: you tagged as javascript, so this tells me you already have a basic idea what to do here. You have a choice. 1) ajax 2) header to same page and ternary operator on your inputs using your entire code in the same file. Seamlessly, then use ajax.

Comment: Btw, I sure hope you're not going live with this, not in its present state. Look up "sql injection".

Answer (score 0):

On the user side theres no difference between html and php, php files are also html in the view of the browser. The only difference is that php files are interpreted by the server ,while html is just send. So you can put your html in your php and mix it all together:

index.php:

```
<body>
<div id="response">
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
//do your request
}else{
echo "please fill in the form";
}
?>
</div>
//your form etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer You can **merge the HTML and PHP files** unless there is a need to separate them (if so use AJAX). Do a validation before any database interaction. **Do not use mysql but mysqli_**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
  $col1 = $col2=$col3=$col4="";
 mysql_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
 @mysql_select_db("trynew") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET["user"])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM trynewtable where name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result==FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $col1 = $row[0];
    $col2 = $row[1];
    $col3 = $row[2];
    $col4 = $row[3];
}
mysql_close();

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $col1." ".$col2." ".$col3." ".$col4;?>
    <form action="" method="get">
    Enter Name : <input type="text" id="txt1" name="user">
    <input type="submit" name="enter">
    </form>
</body>
```